# Javascript: Parse string to duration

Tags: javascript

How to parse strings like `1h 20m`, `30m`, `1 h`, `1 h 30m`, `2:45` to timespan. While rejecting `34r` `45g`, `10:75` etc.

Tried with the following code:

```
function parse(str){
  var result = 0
  // ignore commas
  str = str.replace(/(\d),(\d)/g, '$1$2')
  str.replace(duration, function(_, n, units){
    units = getUnits(units)
      || getUnits[units.toLowerCase().replace(/s$/, '')]
      || 1
    result += parseFloat(n, 10) * units;
  })
  return result;
}

function getUnits(unit){
  var to_ret;
  switch(unit){
    case "seconds":
    case "second":
    case "secs":
    case "sec":
    case "s": to_ret = 0; break;

    case "minutes":
    case "minute":
    case "mins":
    case "min":
    case "m": to_ret = 1; break;

    case "hours":
    case "hour": 
    case "hr":
    case "hrs":
    case "h": to_ret =  60; break;

    case "days":
    case "day":
    case "d": to_ret = 24 * 60; break;

    case "weeks":
    case "week":
    case "w": to_ret = 7 * 24 * 60; break;

    default: to_ret = undefined;
  }

  return to_ret;
}
```

Plunker for above code: https://plnkr.co/edit/7V0Lgj?p=preview

However, the above isn't good enough to recognize what `2:45` means while doesn't give error with `34r`,`45g`, `10:75`.

Now, I could add more conditions however, would like to know if any simple solution to the above issue is available

Comment: By timespan you mean in minutes ? What about 1 h 30 m 45 s ?

Comment: @Aky_0788 Right the code for second would create issues. That is why I mentioned if there is an easy way to parse such a string

Answer (score 1):

Format H:M is kind of different, so I wouldn't try to solve it with 1 regex/1 loop. Also, why settle with multiplier *1 when letters can't be parsed to hours/minutes etc? So, with some error handling, this should be ok: [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/1ZMftPHNh7UrjeSpTm99?p=preview)

```
function parse(str){
  var result = 0
  var error = null;
  // ignore commas
  str = str.replace(/(\d),(\d)/g, '$1$2')
  if (str.indexOf(':')>=0) {
    var arr = str.split(':')
    if (arr.length != 2) error = true;
    else result = parseInt(arr[0])*60+ parseInt(arr[1])

  }
  else str.replace(duration, function(_, n, units){
    units = getUnits(units)
      || getUnits[units.toLowerCase().replace(/s$/, '')]
      || undefined;
    if (typeof units === 'undefined') error = true;
    else result += parseFloat(n, 10) * units;

  })
  return error?null:result;
}
```

Comment: So there are a few issues with this approach. 1. `23` should be interpreted as 23 hours. 2. For a random string like `sfsdfs` the output if `0` while it should be `null`

Comment: Well, there are always some cases you can't prepare for, yet those two above can be solved pretty easily: [edited plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/7fYh4WNPWBzj0kJ93GmH?p=preview)

Comment: Hmm, I guess this code would always have edge cases. I will keep this question open if someone has a better and easy solution to this.

Comment: Why use minutes as the base unit, wouldn't it make more sense to use seconds instead? Also, your code returns `null` for strings with a seconds component, like `"60s"`. PS.: I'm a JS newbie, as you can probably tell :)